# UV unwrap proportions aren't consistent with model

Tags: uv, scale

So I've applied Rotation and Scale to my model in object mode and when I unwrap in edit mode, some sections aren't holding the correct proportions. In the picture you can see what I'm talking about. I'm making a stadium and so the risers are a smaller dimension than the step. On some sections, it unwraps correctly but on others, the steps and risers appear to be the same size.

Is there anything that could be effecting this?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 3):

What ended up fixing the issue for me was to go to the Unwrap operation panel and switch it to Conformal instead of Angle.